# FB.Canvas.pay for Unity Facebook SDK Callback not being called

Tags: facebook, plugins, canvas, sdk, unity-game-engine

Has anyone run into an issue with callbacks not properly being called in a Unity WebPlayer build as a Canvas app on Facebook?

I am using this code:

```
FB.Canvas.Pay(
    product: 'MY_PRODUCT_URL',
    quantity: 1,
    callback: delegate(string response) {
        Debug.Log('The result of the purchase is: " + response);
    });
```

The purchase window pops up as it should with the proper product information and quantity, but when the purchase is successful I can see in the console that the default Debug.Log(response) is being call NOT the custom callback that I assigned. Any ideas why this is happening or has anyone else run into this issue?

This also happens with the FB.Init(onInitComplete, onHideUnity) function. onInitComplete is called as it should be but the onHideUnity callback is never called when a window for facebook (such as the Friends list) is pulled up.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
'MY_PRODUCT_URL'
```

That's just a string.  Replace that with the actual product url you want to use.

```
callback: delegate(string response) {
    Debug.Log('The result of the purchase is: " + response);
}
```

Replace that line with your actual delegate you want to use.

Comment: 'MY_PRODUCT_URL' was just a line I put to represent the URL I have in there. I have a valid URL already in the code itself. 

The delegate I assigned is the one I show in the code which simply prepends "The result of the purchase is: " to the response from Facebook in order to differentiate my delegate from the default delegate of the Facebook SDK. 

The code works fine as it brings up the Purchase window with the quantity specified, the product specified, and the associated product icon. The problem is the delegate I assign is not being called, unfortunately.

Comment: Btw, which version of the Facebook SDK are you using?  You can find the SDK version in the Unity Editor under Facebook -> Edit Settings.

Comment: I am using version 3.1.2. Thanks, Brian, I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Saw there's a new version now. Updated to 4.2.1 and it now works. Thanks to you guys for all your hard work!